# Why am I getting an ever increasing value of power co-efficient (Cp) with the increase of TSR in Vertical axis wind turbine simulation?

Tags: ansys, cfd, ansys-workbench, fluent

I am trying to get the bell-shaped Cp vs TSR graph in my 2D simulation of the H-Darrieus vertical axis wind turbine (using a sliding mesh model). However, I am always getting an ever increase of Cp value with the increase of TSR value i.e. the more I increase the value of the angular velocity of the sliding mesh, the higher the moment coefficient gets. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the bell-shaped curve?
#I am trying to replicate the task of the paper I have attached #I have attached my ANSYS file https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HtQMmDJHReaM3IKPTjSBT0Ru3BtQtxIn?usp=sharing
I am trying to replicate the results of a paper, so it's unlikely that the peak will be far-off. Here's a picture that shows the paper's results, experimental results, and my result. I am trying to get the transition SST model and according to the paper, it is run at inlet velocity 10m/s:
[image]

This is what I have been doing:

I have taken a very simple mesh. I have followed the tutorial of confluence (I replicated both the transient and steady parts. This is the link:https://confluence.cornell.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=333371302)

So far I have understood, to get the Cp vs TSR curve, I have to change the turbine's angular velocity here:
[image]

This is run at 176 rev/min i.e. 18.4307 rad/s. For 10m/s inlet, the TSR will be (omega*turbine Radius)/freestream Velocity=(18.4307*1.125)/10=2.30.

This way, for each TSR point, I have to run the simulation and get the average moment coefficient value(Cm):
[image]

Then, I calculated Cp=Cm*TSR. This way I calculated but always got an increasing value of Cp.

Please let me know if I am making mistakes and how I can fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Just skimming your question, Are you possibly off by magnitude (units? coefficients? coefficients in the correct units?). It is possible it is the right shape but you are just seeing the beginning of it. Objectively stand back and evaluate how close does your model match their model, are you comparing apples to apples? Airfoils and angle of attack the same? Same assumptions?

Comment: Sir, I have checked my procedure and do not think I am making any mistake in the calculations. Still, I have shared what I am doing just in case someone else finds a problem. Please let me know where you think I might be wrong because I am really facing problems identifying it. Thank you

Comment: You might try posting on cfdonline. Here is a similar unresolved question from back in 2017. There may be an issue with the ANSYS model for this application. If you don't get any good answers here or at cfd online I would recommend going to your fluent vendor and seeing if they have any ideas. https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/fluent/194247-cp-increasing-increase-tsr-never-decrease-2d-unsteady-analysis.html

Comment: You appear to believe the blade tip is $1.125\,\mathsf{m}$ from the axis of rotation.  Why?

Comment: @ericnutsch Thank you for your suggestions. I will check it out

Comment: @DanielHatton Sir, The radius of the H-Darrieus wind turbine is 1.25 m.